# Finding values of $t$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have this equation -

$3t^{\frac{1}{2}} - \frac{2}{5} t^{\frac{-3}{2}} = 0 $

I'm struggling on how to find the values of $t$

First, I power both sides by $2$ to make the power be a whole number .

I get

$3t - \frac{2}{5} t^{-3} = 0 $

From here I'm stunned and stuck . Can I get a hint ! Thanks !

Comment: $(a+b)^2 \ne a^2+b^2$ so that won't work.  Substitute $s=t^{1/2} $ instead to get $3s-\frac 25 s^{-3}=0$.

Comment: Se in *substituting* we are *not* squaring.  We are just changing variables.

Answer (score 4):

I don't see how you get the second equation: the square of
$3t^{1/2}-\frac25t^{-3/2}$ is **not**
$3t-\frac25t^{-3}$. Your original equation is
$$3t^{1/2}-\frac{2}{5t^{3/2}}=0.$$
Putting this over a common denominator gives
$$\frac{15t^2-2}{5t^{3/2}}=0.$$
Can you see where to go now?

Answer (score 2):

You can't square.

$(a + b)^2 \ne a^2 + b^2$ but instead equals $a^2 + 2ab + b^2$ so that won't make things simpler.

Also squaring both both sides of an equation will add extraneous solutions.  For example, the problem $x + 1 = 2$ has one solution: $x = 1$.  But if I chose to square both sides $(x+1)^2 = 4^2$ then $x^2 + 2x + 1 = 4$ and $x^2 + 2x - 3 = 0$ so $(x+3)(x-1) = 0$ so $x = 1$ *or* $x = -3$.  So somehow we now have *two* solutions.  Where did $x = -3$ come from and is it a valid solution?

Notice when we say $a = b$ there is only one possibility: $a$ and $b$ are the same thing.  But if we square both sides to get $a^2 = b^2$ there are two possibilities:  $a$ and $b$ are the same thing, or $a$ and $b$ are negatives of each other.

So $x + 1 = 2$ means $x + 1 $ and $2$ are the same thing.  But $(x+1)^2 = 2^2$ means either $x + 1$ and $2$ are the same thing, *OR* $x+1$ and $-2$ are the same thing.  If $x+1 = -2$ we get ..... $x =-3$... which was the new answer that came out of nowhere.  It is not a valid answer because $x + 1 \ne -2$.  We call that an extraneous solution and this often (usually) occurs if we square both sides.

Squaring both sides isn't wrong but we must test for extraneous solutions.

$3t^{\frac 12} - \frac 25 t^{-\frac 32} = 0$

$(3t^{\frac 12} - \frac 25 t^{-\frac 32})^2 = 0$

$9t - 2*3t^{\frac 12}*\frac 25 t^{-\frac 32} + \frac {4}{25}t^{-3} = 0$

$9t - \frac {12}{5t} + \frac {4}{25t^3} = 0$

And ... that's really not any easier... and it wil have extraneous solutions so ... let's not do it.

If getting rid of the fractional powers are *really * a concern (why are they?) then to get rid of them simply do substitution.

Let $r = t^{\frac 12}$.

Then

$3t^{\frac 12} - \frac 25 t^{-\frac 32} = 0 \implies$

$3r - \frac 25 r^{-3} = 0\implies$

$(3r - \frac 25 r^{-3})5r^3 = 0 *5r^3 \implies$

$15r^4 - 2 = 0\implies$

$r^4 = \frac 2{15}\implies$

$r = \pm \sqrt[4]{\frac 2{15}}\implies$

$t^{\frac 12} = \pm \sqrt[4]{\frac 2{15}}$.  But $t^{\frac 12} \ge 0$ so

$t^{\frac 12} = \sqrt[4]{\frac 2{15}}\implies$

$t = \sqrt{\frac 2{15}}$.

But there really isn't any reason to be afraid of the half powers.

Simply put everything over a common denominator:

$3t^{\frac 12} - \frac 25t^{-\frac 32} = 0 \implies$

$\frac {15t^2 - 2}{5t^{\frac 32}} = 0\implies$

$15t^2 - 2 = 0\implies$

$t = \pm \sqrt {\frac {2}{15}}$.

But as $t^{1/2}$ implies $t$ is non-negative.

$t = \sqrt{\frac {2}{15}}$.

Comment: There is a factor of 3 missing in the initial equation.

Comment: Which might explain the arbitrary looking solution.

Comment: Okay, fixed it.

Comment: Your last statement is false. Indeed, the condition $t^{1/2} \in \mathbb{R}$ would imply $t \geq 0$; but this condition is not given. Maybe you confuse it with the (implicit but reasonable) condition $t \in \mathbb{R}$? You can convince yourself that $-\sqrt{\frac{2}{15}}$ solves the equation by plugging it in.

Comment: $(-\sqrt{\frac 2{15}})^{\frac 12}$ doesn't exist in the reals.  We can't plug it in and it is not a valid solution.  If we are limiting ourselves to the real numbers.  Which is a reasonable assumption for a pre-calculus algebra question.

Answer (score 1):

The equation
$$
3t^{\frac{1}{2}} - \frac{2}{5} t^{\frac{-3}{2}} = 0
$$
is equivalent to
$$
t^{\frac{1}{2}} = \frac{2}{15} t^{\frac{-3}{2}} \;.
$$
Since $t$ cannot be zero$\color{green}{^*}$, you are allowed to multiply both sides by $t^{\frac{3}{2}}$:
$$
t^{2} = \frac{2}{15} \;.
$$
So, the solution is
$$
t = \pm\sqrt{\frac{2}{15}} \;.
$$

$\small\color{green}{^*\text{: If $t$ were zero, we would have $0^{\frac{-3}{2}} = \dfrac{1}{0}$.}}$

Comment: $t^{1/2}$ being a real implies $t \ge 0$.

Comment: @fleadbood: So what?

Comment: So $t = - \sqrt{\frac 2{15}} $ is not a solution. $3(-\sqrt{\frac{2}{15}})^{\frac 12} - \frac 25 (-\sqrt{\frac 2{15}})^{-\frac 32} \ne 0$.

Comment: It is zero: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=3+*+%7B-sqrt(2%2F15)%7D%5E%7B1%2F2%7D+-+2+%2F+5+*+%7B-sqrt(2%2F15)%7D%5E%7B-3%2F2%7D

Comment: Wolfram is using complex numbers definition.  It's undefined in the reals.